# Why the combination of past perfect with past simple does not work here

Tags: past-tense

> was not expecting you to contact me again!!
>
> I **had tried** to contact you so many times and **did not receive** an answer so much so that I had completely forgotten that I had made an order. I was very surprised to receive an email from you today.

In a reply to a question I asked, Vegawatcher answered that it was not possible to write "did not receive" in this case. The combination of "had tried" with "did not receive" does not work. "Had tried" must be followed by "had received". Vegawatcher did not write why, but he added it would be also ok if both verbs were past simple, but again he did not explain why.

I really don't understand why "had tried" can't go with "did not receive" in this case or why past simple would be also ok, knowing that the attempt of contacting the seller ended a long time before receiving the email. So past perfect should be obligatory for this verb.

Comment: I think that Vegawatcher must have wanted the tenses to concur, but I agree with you: If the "trying" occurred before the "not receiving", then it is fine for the former to be in the past perfect and the latter to be in the smiple past.

Comment: English speakers often don't bother with the _had_ construction when the termporal relationships are clear without it.

Comment: Could have I written   "so much so that I had completely forgotten I made an order " I don't think so because it will mean for me that the order was made after I had forgotten which is not true . It seems to me that past perfect is obligatory here. May be this will be solved by writing " I completely forgot I had made an order."